# Find the limit or prove it does not exist for the following rational function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{x^2y^2 + 2x^2 + 4}{xy - x - 2}$$

All linear approaches ( as in, using $y = m(x-1)$ ) converge to $-2$, so I tried to prove this using epsilon-delta definition, but I don't know which inequalities to use at any step

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicating things a little.

There's no problem with division by zero in this case, so the function (being rational) is continuous at the point $(1,0)$, and therefore you can find the limit simply by substituting $(x,y)=(1,0)$ into the expression.